# How can I select the only filled/colored cell in a column?

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently working with a workbook that utilizes a row of cells that are colored/filled grey to separate between two sets of data. There isn't any real structure to the way the worksheet it set up, but if I can extract the data to a new sheet then I can format it with some other code I have. The first step for extracting the data would be for me to get to the second data set, which I can do if I can select the row of colored/filled cells. I attempted to use the record function and have come up with the following code:

```
Application.FindFormat.Clear
    Columns("A:A").Select
    With Application.FindFormat.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = -0.14996795556505
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.Find(What:="", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=True).Activate
ActiveCell.Select
End Sub
```

The problem is that the above code activates/selects a blank cell with no fill. If anyone could provide me with some insight as to why that might be the case, I would really appreciate that.

Alternatively, if anyone has an idea as to how I can search a specific column for the only filled/colored cell and then return/select that cell address, that would be equally helpful.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: I think the last line of code (ActiveCell.Select) is where it might be stuffing you up.  I've given an answer but if you delete the line, see if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to do things using my own approach rather than the in built way, I find it's then easier for me to debug.  That's not true in all cases but with this approach, it is.

Throw this function into a new module in VBA ...

```
Public Function GetColoredCells(ByVal rngCells As Range) As Range
    Dim objCell As Range, strCells As String

    For Each objCell In rngCells.Cells
        If objCell.Interior.ColorIndex <> xlColorIndexNone Then
            strCells = strCells & "," & Replace(objCell.Address, "$", "")
        End If
    Next

    strCells = Trim(Mid(strCells, 2))

    Set GetColoredCells = rngCells.Range(strCells)
End Function

Public Sub YourRoutineToCopyAndPaste()
    Dim rngCells As Range

    Set rngCells = GetColoredCells(Sheet1.Range("A1:G13"))

    ' From here, you can work with the individual cells that the
    ' GetColoredCells function returned.

    rngCells.Select
End Sub
```

It doesn't necessarily give you the exact outcome to what you require but you can do something with the logic and it demonstrates the approach.  I trust you can take it to the next step.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the help! I haven't done much with functions so this was really great for me to dive into. After putting in your code I came up with the following:   
  ```Dim ColoredRange As String

Range("W1").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=GetColoredCells(A:A)"
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    ActiveCell.Select
    
TestThis = Range("W1").Value
Range(ColoredRange).Activate

End Sub```       My formatting sucks, but essentially this takes a long time to run, I believe because it's searching every row in column A- any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, you're way off but 10 points for trying.  :-)  Also, yes, no fancy formatting in comments on here.  If you want to use that function from within VBA then I'd suggest simply calling it but a word of warning, you need to make sure you only select the range of data that you're concerned with, selecting A:A will create a huge performance overhead.  I'll be honest, I'm trying not to get sucked in to building your entire solution but given you're trying, I'll update my answer with a way you can implement that function from within VBA.

Comment: I wouldn't be selecting and then copying and pasting like it does when you record a macro but if that works for you then so be it.  My answer has been udpated.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am amazed at how condensed the sub code is now. I am still so new to this stuff that this was really exciting for me. I appreciate you updating your answer. If it makes you feel any better I promise I will be going through everything you did until I understand it!

Comment: @StunnedbymyStupidity that's ok, always happy to help.  As you've probably noticed on Stackoverflow, the community expect people to help themselves so you've got the right attitude.  Just try and stay away from .select ... it's not the best way to code logic.  Also, remember to flag this (or another answer if that's the way you go) as the answer if it helps you to the point where you're able to move forward, it helps everybody and gives people like me incentive to keep helping others.

Comment: Bahaha @Skin I just added `rcell.select` I'm not 100% sure what OP is trying to do, but I though my method would be a good start. I like that you used a function to create a range! I just started getting into functions myself. I also have never used `.select` unless it was for testing/debugging but I have seen SO posts which that was the issue, unneeded `.select` statements causing issues.

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers, yeah, it's ok in the context of someone who is just starting out.  I don't have a problem because the exact requirement in this case is not 100% clear to me so if he can take an answer (like one on ours) and then start running his own code with that result using .select and the like then he gets his result.  Otherwise, I'll need to do more work to understand the exact requirement and then code the rest of the solution.  Plus, it's good practice and he's willing to learn so I say go for it ...!  You learn by doing and we don't always do things the best way first up.  :-)

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers our answers (were originally) quite similar so although he flagged mine, I upvoted yours.  I was more trying to lead him to his own destiny (if that makes sense).  I think your message box threw him but I understood what you were doing so it's worth a vote if not the answer.  If you got there before me and I shut my mouth, you had it for sure.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'd do it, just adjust `rng` and then add code for `MsgBox`

```
Public Sub FindFilled()

Dim rng As Range
Dim rcell As Range
Set rng = Range("A1:A255")

  For Each rcell In rng.Cells
        If rcell.Interior.ColorIndex <> xlColorIndexNone Then
                MsgBox "Shading in Cell" & rcell.Address ' Do Code Here
                rcell.select
        End If
  Next rcell
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your response! My only question is- instead of having a message box, is there a way to directly navigate to the cell that gets identified?

Comment: @StunnedbymyStupidity I mean, I added `.select` which will `navigate` you there, but I'm not sure that's what you want. What is the end goal? Break down your problems, you have now identified how to find cells with shading by looping through a range, whats your next step?